# Wordpress - Create link to separate author archive inside blog post

Tags: php, wordpress

We're developing a blog in Wordpress and have come across some functionality that we're having some difficulty implementing.

Our client wants to be able to mention blog users in a blog post, this will then take the end user to the mentioned authors profile. Example below:

`"We recently spoke to our newest team member Pete Smith"` or `"We recently spoke to our newest team member @PeteSmith"`

If you were to click on Pete's name it would take you to `website.com/authors/petesmith`

I know that Wordpress has mentioning functionality built into the comments section, but is there a way to achieve this inside actual blog posts?

Apologies that I can't include any code on this question, there simply is nothing to show you guys.

Comment: How about simply creating a link on the name whose address is copied from the URL of the author page?

Comment: While that would work, not all the users at the client's offices will understand how to do it in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this inside your functions.php:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'the_content_func');

function the_content_func($content) {
    $ret = preg_replace_callback ( "/(@[A-Za-z]+)/",
        function ($match) {
            $authorName = mb_substr($match[0], 1);
            $author = get_user_by('slug', $authorName);
            if ( ! empty( $author ) )
                return '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url( $author->ID, $author->user_nicename ) . '">' . $author->display_name . '</a>';
            else
                return $authorName;
        },
    $content);
    return $ret;
}
```

I assume that the text after @ symbol is the author's slug, so inside the filter I search for the given author and if he's found, output the corresponding author profile link with the display name. Otherwise I just output the string without @ symbol & URL.

If I misunderstood your goals, feel free to modify the inner function of preg_replace_callback keeping in mid that $match[0] contains found user slug with @ symbol from the post content.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think we can work with this. So the code above will just scrape through all of the content and replace the @ with a link? I'll give this a shot after lunch and let you know how I get on :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is code for author archive page

```
<a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' ) ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a>
```

Comment: This isn't to link to the Author's page, this is to link to a *different* authors profile from inside the post body